# Cakephp Relationships

Tags: cakephp, entity-relationship, relational-database, cakephp-1.3

I have a few models which are not in the default cakephp format

**user(id, name....)**

```
1 Harsha ...
2 John ....
```

**dishes(id, name, price ...)**

```
1 "Cheese Pizza" 6
2 "Zinger Burger" 3
```

**restaurants (id, name, .....)**

```
1 "KFC" ...
2 "Pizza Hut" ...
```

**module(id, name) values (User, Dishes, Restaurants)**

```
1 "Users"
2 "Dishes"
3 "Restaurant"
```

---

**items (id, module_id, item_id)**

```
1 1 1 (refers to User Harsha)

2 3 2 (refers to Pizza hut)

3 2 2 (refers to Zinger Burger)

4 1 2 (refers to User John)
```

where item_id refers to the Id of Users, Dishes or Rests Depending on the module_id

---

**reviews (id, parent_id, review, time, item_id, commenter_id)**

```
1 0 "Best Burger in the world" "time" 3 1 (refers to Harsha reviewing Zinger Burger)

2 1 "Yes i love Zingers tooo" time 3 2 ( refers to John replying to Harsha's Review)
```

I am a little messged up on how to draw up the relationships in cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book at this page: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together you'll find a guide to the possible keys you can set on the relationship, e.g.

> foreignKey: the name of the foreign
>   key found in the other model. This is
>   especially handy if you need to define
>   multiple hasOne relationships. The
>   default value for this key is the
>   underscored, singular name of the
>   current model, suffixed with ‘_id’. In
>   the example above it would default to
>   'user_id'.

Assuming reviews and items are children in their associations, for both ends of the relationships, you'd set the foreignKey as 'item_id'.

Something like:

```
dishes:
class Dish extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Dish'; 
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'className'     => 'Item',
            'foreignKey'    => 'item_id',
            ...
items:
class Item extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Item'; 
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Dish' => array(
            'className'     => 'Dish',
            'foreignKey'    => 'item_id',
            ...
            ),

        'Restaurant' => array(
            'className'     => 'Restaurant',
            'foreignKey'    => 'item_id',
            ...
```

It's difficult to be more precise, but you haven't provided any datamodel. To handle the selection of Model via the Module, you'll need to write some code on a model somewhere, which one(s) depends on how you access the data.

However, it looks to me like a good time to restructure the database!

Comment: the confusion is Item belongs to say User. so belongsTo should be like this http://pastebin.com/uVrbzVQi and not to Item right ?